# Assertion failure in [CustomNavigationController popToViewController:transition:]

Tags: objective-c, xcode, ios7, uinavigationcontroller

I want to pop view controllers until the desired view controller is at the top of the navigation stack.

I'm doing it this way:

```
UIViewController *aViewController = [self.navigationController.viewControllers objectAtIndex:lViewControllerIndex];
[self.navigationController popToViewController:aViewController
                                                animated:YES];
```

From the debugger I can see that `aViewController` is `<MainViewController: 0x79ea3b10>`
and `self.navigationController.viewControllers` is

```
<MainViewController: 0x79ea3b10>,
<FirstViewController: 0x79eb2630>,
<SecondViewController: 0x7b258f10>
```

Currently I'm in `SecondViewController` and I want to go back to `MainViewController`

But it crashes, the crash message is the following:

```
***** Assertion failure in -[CustomNavigationController popToViewController:transition:], /SourceCache/UIKit_Sim/UIKit-2935.137/UINavigationController.m:4912**
```

How can I correctly go back by popping multiple view controller ?

**UPDATED [1]:
I was not clear, I don't need a way how to pop to root view controller, I need a way how to pop multiple view controllers. Above, it was only an example going from `SecondViewController` to `MainViewController`**

**UPDATED [2]:**

Stack trace:

```
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x030a81e4 __exceptionPreprocess + 180
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x02e218e5 objc_exception_throw + 44
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x030a8048 +[NSException raise:format:arguments:] + 136
    3   Foundation                          0x00c7d4de -[NSAssertionHandler handleFailureInMethod:object:file:lineNumber:description:] + 116
    4   UIKit                               0x01a45ab8 -[UINavigationController popToViewController:transition:] + 918
    5   UIKit                               0x01a4571d -[UINavigationController popToViewController:animated:] + 56
    6   Isi For You                         0x000a14b7 -[DetailViewController breadcrumbItemPressedAtIndex:] + 327
    7   Isi For You                         0x000c4460 -[ListHeaderViewController breadcrumbView:didTapItemAtIndex:] + 144
    8   Isi For You                         0x00094772 -[BTBreadcrumbView didTapItemAtIndex:] + 162
    9   Isi For You                         0x0009480f -[BTBreadcrumbView tapItemButton:] + 143
    10  libobjc.A.dylib                     0x02e33880 -[NSObject performSelector:withObject:withObject:] + 77
    11  UIKit                               0x018fe3b9 -[UIApplication sendAction:to:from:forEvent:] + 108
    12  UIKit                               0x018fe345 -[UIApplication sendAction:toTarget:fromSender:forEvent:] + 61
    13  UIKit                               0x019ffbd1 -[UIControl sendAction:to:forEvent:] + 66
    14  UIKit                               0x019fffc6 -[UIControl _sendActionsForEvents:withEvent:] + 577
    15  UIKit                               0x019ff243 -[UIControl touchesEnded:withEvent:] + 641
    16  UIKit                               0x0193dddd -[UIWindow _sendTouchesForEvent:] + 852
    17  UIKit                               0x0193e9d1 -[UIWindow sendEvent:] + 1117
    18  UIKit                               0x019105f2 -[UIApplication sendEvent:] + 242
    19  Isi For You                         0x00434244 -[CustomUIApplication sendEvent:] + 100
    20  UIKit                               0x018fa353 _UIApplicationHandleEventQueue + 11455
    21  CoreFoundation                      0x0303177f __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 15
    22  CoreFoundation                      0x0303110b __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 235
    23  CoreFoundation                      0x0304e1ae __CFRunLoopRun + 910
    24  CoreFoundation                      0x0304d9d3 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 467
    25  CoreFoundation                      0x0304d7eb CFRunLoopRunInMode + 123
    26  GraphicsServices                    0x042cc5ee GSEventRunModal + 192
    27  GraphicsServices                    0x042cc42b GSEventRun + 104
    28  UIKit                               0x018fcf9b UIApplicationMain + 1225
    29  Isi For You                         0x000449e2 main + 82
    30  libdyld.dylib                       0x038796d9 start + 1
)
```

Answer (score 3):

That error usually occurs when the View Controller you are trying to pop to is not in the navigation stack. Although in your case it would seem that you view controller is in fact there... You can use [`popToRootViewControllerAnimated:`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UINavigationController_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UINavigationController/popToRootViewControllerAnimated:) to pop to your "root".

```
[self.navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

Comment: Thanks, but this isn't desired solution for me, see my edited question.

Comment: Does your error show any other information? Something like `Terminating app due to uncaught exception...`

Comment: I've added stack trace

Answer (score 1):

If you try to pop without animation it will work. I faced this issue when tried to pop multiple view controllers animated.

If you want to pop n viewControllers till n-1 pop without animation, then pop the last one with animation.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the

`- (void)setViewControllers:(NSArray *)viewControllers animated:(BOOL)animated`

API on `UINavigationController` to hop between multiple stack position jumps or indeed completely replace the stack.

from the docs

> The view controllers to place in the stack. The front-to-back order of
>   the controllers in this array represents the new bottom-to-top order
>   of the controllers in the navigation stack. Thus, the last item added
>   to the array becomes the top item of the navigation stack.

so recover your current stack with the `viewControllers` property , mutate as desired (in your case you would be taking a sub-array of the original stack) then dump it back onto the navigation controller.

Comment: Do you know if this follows the VC lifecycle? i.e. what if he has some code in `viewDidDisappear`? Will this still get invoked?

Comment: no idea - but the top view controller doesn't know or care that its part of a nav stack . if its being pulled out of the window hierachy as part of this API then i assume it receives its regular will-didDisappear calls